# Is it haram to have friends of opposite gender of neighbours and in school?

Tags: women, friendship, school

Assalamualaikum, i am actually student in school, i actually have some female classmates of mine who i usually go for study related stuff and i also give them my work if they need it, i don't have any kind of haram intention about them and we only talk in school snd never any other place only except if they need my notes and i also have a friend of opposite gender who is my neighbour, she's been my friend since we were 3 years old because we were neighbour, is this friendship haram

Answer (score 0):

I write my interpretation of the rules of religion.
Most rulings of religion have a preventive aspect. That is, most of them are set for prevention and personal health or family and social relationships. That is, if we examine them carefully, behaviors that may lead to crime and damage to important relationships (family or social) are prohibited.

Relationships and friendships with the opposite sex are the same. There may be no bad intentions at first. But there are points. You are aware of your own intentions, not the intentions of the other person. The situation is likely to change over time as emotions and circumstances change. And you may incline to sin. This is how most unpleasant events start.
So a wise man avoids walking on the edge of the abyss. Taqwa requires that you observe all aspects of caution in relations with the opposite sex.